# AS3: Random Color Generator For User Drawn Line

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, line

So I've been looking around and I have tried a few different things and still can't seem to get a random color generator to work with this user drawn line. Here's the code that I am working with for the user drawn line.

```
var myshape:Shape;
myshape = new Shape();
myshape.graphics.lineStyle(8, 0x99CC33);
myshape.filters = [new BlurFilter()];

function activateDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myshape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    addChild(myshape);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);
}

function lineDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myshape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    event.updateAfterEvent();
}

function stopDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);

    myshape.graphics.clear();
    myshape.graphics.lineStyle(12, 0x99CC33);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
var myshape:Shape;
myshape = new Shape();
myshape.graphics.lineStyle(8, Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
myshape.filters = [new BlurFilter()];

function activateDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myshape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    addChild(myshape);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);
}

function lineDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myshape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    event.updateAfterEvent();
}

function stopDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);

    myshape.graphics.clear();
    myshape.graphics.lineStyle(8, Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
}
```